# Does AdBlock download the ad but just not display it, or does it stop the downloading of the ad completely?

Tags: advertisements

Just curious: does AdBlock download the ad but just not display it? Or does it stop the downloading of the ad entirely, which means that the display of the ad never happens at all?

Comment: As far as I know it doesn't, but you can easily achieve this by editing your HOSTS file.

Comment: Adblock Plus for firefox or Adblock for Chrome? Adblock for Chrome definitely blocks the download; it is explicitly mentioned in the feature list. I believe Adblock Plus for firefox does too though I can't find a source for it.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not clear which app you mean by "AdBlock", most such software does both:
blocks network requests for ad-related files, and also prevents the browser display, by using CSS rules,for elements that can't be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about AdBlock Plus.

When a webpage is loaded, the browser download the HTML document.  It parses through the documents and build a DOM tree; the DOM tree is a specialised structure that keeps all elements (e.g. images, text, layout, font, video, scripts, plugins...) to be displayed.  The browser then download the external elements referred in the DOM tree and render the whole webpage.

AdBlock works by removing the element to be blocked from the HTML DOM tree directly, before the webpage is rendered.  It could be the ad banner itself, tracking elements, or even scripts that displays the ad.

Therefore, the ad element is already disappeared when the browser is about to render the webpage, and the ad will never be downloaded.

You can verify the understanding by inspecting the DOM tree (e.g. by DOM inspector in Firefox).